# codeigniter locatization other than stock lang class

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization, html-parsing

is there any better for locatlization other than time-wasting lang() class ?

current apporach

index.php view

in language file i have to set both default lang and other language. but i find this to be a bit distracting and waste of time to have to go to lang file every time i need to show a word/paragraph. and if i dont set english lang it will show empty line.

so is there an already existing methode that would allow me to develope freely and when loading view to check all visible text and search for its alternative in other lang (if set) other leave as is ?

for example

```
<h1 data-lang='login'>please login<h1>
<p><label for='username'>Username</label><input name='username' /></p>
<p><label for='username'>Password</label><input name='password' /></p>
```

and localization parse all tags and search for data-lang to find lang_ key, if it doesnt exist then LEAVE MY DEFAULT ALONE..? and if label search by for='' value for example

thats a rough idea i think will make my life better..yet if there is any better solutions that doesnt require me to separate default lang into its own file i would love to hear about.

also how can i parse html in codeigniter ?

Comment: use standart functions for this. 
Read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html